# submit in for not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an index page with a div container.
I have for on page create_node_group.php
i am loading creating_node_group in div container of index page which is loading properly and contains a form.
When i submit the form nothing happens.

my .js is

```
$("#create_node_group").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit 
    alert("submit called");

    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#content').html(response); // update the DIV

        }
    });
```

this is my create_node_group which loads properly in index page container div. when i submit the form nothing happens.

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
$query = "select * from monitor_template";
$template = array();
$row_num;
$result=pg_query($conn, $query);
  if  (!$result) {
   echo "query did not execute";
  }
  if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   echo "0 records";
  }
  else {
      $a=0;
   while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { 
     //do stuff with $row
     $template[$a][0]=$row[mon_template_id];
     $template[$a][1]=$row[template_name];
     $a=$a+1;
   }
  }
$row_num=pg_num_rows($result);  //row count starts from 0
//echo 'rows returned are: '.$row_num;
//print_r($template);
//echo $template[0][0].'-'.$template[0][1].'--'.$template[1][0].'-'.$template[1][1];
?>
<table>
<form class="content_form" id="create_node_group" name = "create_node_group" action="process_create_node_group.php" method="post">
<tr><td>
Node Group Path: </td> <td><input type="text" name="path"></td></tr>

<tr><td>
Node Group ID: </td><td><input type="text" name="node_group_id" disabled="disabled"></td></tr>

<tr><td>
Node Group Name:</td> <td> <input type="text" name="node_group_name"></td></tr>


<?php 
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
 echo '<tr><td>';
 echo 'Monitoring Template '. $i.':</td><td> <select id="Mon_template'.$i.'" name="Mon_template'.$i.'">';
 echo ' <option value="">Select</option>';   
 for($j=0;$j<$row_num;$j++)
 {
    echo '<option value="'.$template[$j][0].'">'.$template[$j][1].'</option>';
 }
 echo  '</select >';
 echo '</td></tr>';

}
?>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 1):

since you are loading the form via ajax i believe that this is because your form is not live try

```
$(document).on('submit','#create_node_group'(function() { // catch the form's submit 
alert("submit called");

$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
    success: function(response) { // on success..
        $('#content').html(response); // update the DIV

    }
});
```